# Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3] | Failed to determine the https port for redirect | .Net Application | Nginx

Tags: .net, nginx

We have one .Net application which is working fine on Nginx ubuntu. But there is another .Net application when we run on the same server post login in web application it gives 502 error.

As one Application working but another is not so we check logs of .net on the server

sudo journalctl -fu kestrel-helloapp.service

Logs-

---

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {XXXXXX} was not found in the key ring.
Repeat 2 times:
at Interop+Sys.GetHostEntryForName(System.String, HostEntry*)
at System.Net.NameResolutionPal.TryGetAddrInfo(System.String, Boolean, System.String ByRef, System.String[] ByRef, System.Net.IPAddress[] ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(System.String, Boolean)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.String)
at CS.Globals.LogError(System.Exception, System.String)
at CS.Globals.LogError(System.Exception, System.String)
at CS.Globals.LogError(System.Exception, System.String)

systemd[1]: kestrel-helloapp.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
systemd[1]: kestrel-helloapp.service: Failed with result 'signal'.

---